# How to update status_payment after receive IPN Paypal?

Tags: sql-update, paypal-ipn

I know to update status_payment order is "completed". Code do the following

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE invoiceID=$_POST['invoice']");
```

Before receive IPN Paypal. What should I store the value for the field invoiceID ???

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking, could you please clarify your question.  Are you asking what to store for the invoice id?  The invoice id would be passed back in the IPN with the same value that you passed over in the payment when it was made.

Comment: Yes. How to create invoice_id with the value = value of $_POST['invoice'] get form IPN ?